# How to store adb path for later use while terminal command?

Tags: android, sdk, terminal, android-sdk-plugin

I am using command prompt run and debug application.But everytime I open terminal (After Restarting Android Studio) terminal path is like

```
E:\tushar\androidStudioWorkspace\Myapp\Myapp>
```

and I have to manually navigate to platform-tools folder.I want the termianal pointet to be at

```
F:\android\newPath\sdk\platform-tools>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your environment varibale path with:

F:\android\newPath\sdk\platform-tools\; F:\android\newPath\sdk\tools\

**How to edit a system variable**

```
1. Click Start (Orb) menu button.
2. Right click on Computer icon.
3. Click on Properties. This will bring up System window in Control Panel.
4. Click on Advanced System Settings on the left. This will bring up the System Properties window with Advanced tab selected.
5. Click on Environment Variables button on the bottom of the dialog. This brings up the Environment Variables dialog.
6. In the System Variables section, scroll down till you see Path.
7. Click on Path to select it, then the Edit button. This will bring up the Edit System Variable dialog.
8. While the Variable value field is selected, press the End key on your keyboard to go to the right end of the line, or use the arrow keys to move the marker to the end.
9. Type in PATH and click OK.
```

that's it!!

Comment: I have already set my environment path to : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;%path%;

Comment: Please set Adb as well. Try once.

Comment: That is not solving my problem of running adb command any where inside "Android Studio Terminal".